# Adding a condition to desplay a list of values in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I need help with putting a condition on a List Of Values in Oracle apex. So I have 2 tables:

```
SELECT v.ID_VEZ      NUMBER
       v.BROJ_VEZ,   NUMBER
       v.MAX_DULJINA FLOAT
       FROM VEZ v
```

and

```
SELECT b.ID_BRODICE            NUMBER
       b.REGISTRACIJA_BRODICE  VARCHAR2(50)
       b.DULJINA_BRODICE       FLOAT
       b.VEZ_FK                NUMBER
       FROM BRODICE b
```

The list of values displays `v.BROJ_VEZ` but returns `v.ID_VEZ`. The LOV is displayed in the form for the table `BRODICE`. I want the LOV to display only the `v.BROJ_VEZ` (returning `v.ID_VEZ`) where `v.MAX_DULJINA > b.DULJINA_BRODICE`. How do I do that ?. Is that even possible as a where clause in the LOV editor or do I need to make a dynamic action for it as the condition must be met only after my user wrote something in the form filed for `b.DULJINA_BRODICE`.

I'm 99% sure no one will understand what I want but I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presume this is page `P1`. Duljina brodice is then entered into `P1_DULJINA_BRODICE` item. Vez LoV would then reference page item as

```
select v.broj_vez as display_value,
       v.id_vez   as return_value
from vez v 
where v.max_duljina > :P1_DULJINA_BRODICE
```

In order for it to properly work, scroll a little bit down (below the LoV query) and you'll see the **Cascading list of values** set of properties.  Put `P1_DULJINA_BRODICE` into **Parent Item(s)** property.

(If query referenced some more page items, you'd name them all in "Parent Item(s)", comma-separated).

That should do it; you don't need dynamic action.

Sretan put i mirno more!

Comment: I love you! Everything works and i must admit as funny as it sounds this 4 lines of code cost me all day yesterday.   Also is there any way i can contact you directly if i have any more questions as i see you are a fellow Croatian ?

Comment: I'm glad if it helped. Unfortunately, I'm not available outside of this community.

Comment: Absolitely fair, sorry for asking! Thank you a ton again and have a nice day !

Comment: No problem at all :)